# DataWeave match function

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Why doesn't this regex works in dataweave? I am expecting it to return 'code=testvalue' as one of the array elements, but I get nothing. My aim is to extract the "testvalue" from the url.

```
var test = 'https://test?code=testvalue&state=state'
output application/java 
---
test match /code=([^&]*)/
```

Comment: Found the answer. Instead of "match", it needs "scan" function. So test scan /code=([^&]*)/ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting remember the old saying that [if you use regular expressions to solve a problem then you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

`match()` requires a regular expression that matches the full input string. That could be useful to avoid ambiguities. `scan()` can match a substring but if the same pattern can happen in other parts of the input it could be a false possitive. For example in your case if it could happen in a query parameters somehow. To avoid that potential issue, even if the probability could be low I used a slightly different regular expression. Even so it doesn't cover the case that the `code` query parameter is in the right position.

```js
output application/java 
var test = "https://test?code=testvalue&state=state"
---
test match (/https:\/\/[^?]*\?code=(.*)(?=&).*/) // Don't do this
```

Regular expressions are not the best tool to solve this problem. It is safer to use a DataWeave provided function to parse URLs. Unfortunately it doesn't parse query parameters so there is still a bit of manual processing left to the script to split the string into individual key-values, then split key and value, then convert each into a DataWeave key-value and add to the result object (using `reduce()`). I encapsulated the code in a function for easier reuse:

```js
output application/json 
var testUrl = "https://test?code=testvalue&state=state"
import * from dw::core::URL
fun getQueryParamsFromUrl(u: String)=parseURI(u).query 
    splitBy "&" 
    map ($ splitBy "=")
    reduce ((item, acc={}) -> acc ++ {(item[0]): item[1]})
---
getQueryParamsFromUrl(testUrl).code
```

It is a few lines longer but simpler, safer and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Following works.

```
var test = 'https://test?code=testvalue&state=state'
output application/java 
---
(test scan /code=([^&]*)/)[0][1]
```